# Im making a multiple choice question using kivy. I dont know how to track correct answers

Tags: kivy

I am a newbie in programming and badly needed help for our activity.
Im making a multiple choice question using kivy. I dont know how to track correct answers.

```
class OneQuestion(Screen):
    correct = 0
    mistake = 0

    def checkbox_click(self, instance, value, answer):
        if answer == 1:
            correct = + 1
        else:
            mistake = + 1
    global current_answer
    answer= "You made " + str(correct) + " correct answers"
    global current_error
    error= "You made " + str(mistake) + " wrong answers"
    current_answer = answer
    current_error = error

    def show_data(self):
        self.dialog = MDDialog(title = "Result", text =current_answer,
                               pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5},
                               buttons=[MDFlatButton(text='Close', on_release=self.close_dialog),
                                        MDFlatButton(text='Return', on_release=self.close_dialog2)]

                               )

        self.dialog.open()

    def close_dialog(self, obj):
        self.dialog.dismiss()

    def close_dialog2(self, obj):
        self.dialog.dismiss()
        self.manager.current = 'exercise'
```

Kivy file:

```
<OneQuestion>
  name: 'quest1'
GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        canvas:
            MDLabel
               text:"option 1"
               font_size:20

            CheckBox:
               color: 0,0,1
               on_active: root.checkbox_click(self,self.active, 0)

            MDLabel
              text:"option 2"
              font_size:20

            CheckBox:
              color: 0,0,1
              on_active: root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,1)


          MDLabel
             text:"option 3"
             font_size:20

          CheckBox:
             color: 0,0,1
             on_active: root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,0)

          MDLabel
             text:"option 4"
             font_size:20

          CheckBox:
             color: 0,0,1
             on_active: root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,1)


          BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                size_hint_y: 0.2
                Button:
                    text: 'Back'
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'exercise'

                Button:
                    text: 'Submit'
                    on_release: root.show_data()
```

Comment: Part of your code is not formatted, pls format it as code, if you want to reach the minimum amount of text to ask a question, then add more details about your problem, and tell us what you've tried, and how you think you can solve your problem. All this will help us, to help you better.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.